# Creating dynamic form ,Its values change across all the copy fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, react-native, dynamicform

```
  const [formSectionData, setFormSectionData] = useState([
    {id: 1, text: ''},
    {id: 2, text: ''},
   ]);

  const addSection = section => {
    let existingForm = [...formSectionData];
    existingForm.push(section);
    setFormSectionData(existingForm);
  };

  const onTextChange = (text, index) => {
    let existingForm = [...formSectionData];
    existingForm[index].text = text;
    setFormSectionData(existingForm);
   };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      {formSectionData.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <View style={{padding: 15}} key={index}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addSection(item)}>
              <Text>+ Add Section</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        <TextInput
          key={index}
          placeholder={'Enter value' + index}
          value={item.text}
          onChangeText={text => onTextChange(text, index)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  })}
</SafeAreaView>);
```

I'm trying to create a new input field using addsection, But now when I'm enter a value to the input field same value will appear in app its original input fields, How to properly add a new  input field from the existing json[image]
[Code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dynamic-form-fields-forked-5lu4v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: select specific state `text` with index and update it accordingly. `let existingForm = [...formSectionData]; setFormSectionData(existingForm);` It will update all of the data

Comment: @DeC Code updated, This is correct ?It doesn't work